# Auto redirect Amazon CloudFront content from www to non-www

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm really new to Amazon CloudFront.

I have **set up an S3 with Cloudfront**, then I'm using a **custom domain** that I setup in CloudFlare.

I can access my photo normally with this kind of link : `https://cdn.example.com/img.jpg`

But then, when I try to open it with the www version, `https://www.cdn.example.com/img.jpg`

The content won't open and give error.

See here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Viz.jpg]

Is there any solution available to auto redirect to non www ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront .......................................

Answer (score 0):

I see you are experiencing a DNS issue. The reason you could not open the address is that the DNS www.cdn.example.com was not found, because you probably didn't set it up in your DNS configuration.

You can fix it by adding a CNAME record in DNS Management, which would be a line like this in your DNS configuration:

```
www.cdn.example.com CNAME   cdn.example.com
```

After the time it takes to propagate, you can verify it works.